# How to redirect/rewrite a domain-1/dir1/dir2/* to another domain-2/dir1/dir2/* in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all URLS from one directory in one domain to the same directory to another domain on the same server, and could not make it work. How do I solve this problem?

I have tried:

#### Attempt 1

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dir1\/dir2(.*)$ https://domain-2.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

#### Attempt 2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2(.*)$ https://domain-2.org/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

#### Desired Output:

I'm hoping to redirect all URLS similar to these patterns:

```
www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-1
www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-2
www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-N

https://domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-1
https://domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-2
https://domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-N

http://domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-1
http://domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-2
http://domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-N

https://www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-1
https://www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-2
https://www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-N

http://www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-1
http://www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-2
http://www.domain-1.org/dir1/dir2/url-N
```

to:

```
https://domain-2.org/dir1/dir2/url-1
https://domain-2.org/dir1/dir2/url-2
https://domain-2.org/dir1/dir2/url-N
```

#### RegEx:

https://regex101.com/r/2BD1kB/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^dir1\/dir2(.*)$ https://domain-2.org/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

Assuming you have `RewriteEngine On` in both cases, your two "attempts" are really *the same*. `RewriteBase` is irrelevant here.

The `$1` backreference refers to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `(.*)` - everything *after* `/dir1/dir2` - so this isn't going to redirect to the "same directory" on the other domain.

Since both domains point to the same server (and I assume the same location on the filesystem) then you need to explicitly check for the domain (ie. *hostname*) in your redirect.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-1\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/.* https://domain-2.org/$0 [R=302,L]
```

`$0` is a backreference to the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. eg. `dir1/dir2/url-N`.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Test with a 302 and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you have confirmed this works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.